# How to delete all json files within directory NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, express, path

I need to delete only the json files within a directory (multiple levels). I'd hazard a guess that it's possible with fs-unlinkSync(path)

But I can't find a solution without specifying the individual file name.

I was hoping to solve it with the following...
fs.unlinkSync('./desktop/directory/*.json')
but unfortunately the asterisk wouldn't select all. Any suggestion please?

Comment: You need to use fs.readdir(Sync) to get a list of files, then iterate over them.

Comment: Can you open this please? How can I specify json files and delete them

Comment: `fs.readdir` returns a list of filenames as Array, so if you then use `filenames.forEach(filename => { ... })` you can now check the `filename` for ending in `.json` for instance by matching it against `/\.json$/i`, and delete it if it does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can list files using fs.readdirSync, then call fs.unlinkSync to delete. This can be called recursively to traverse an entire tree.

```
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");

function deleteRecursively(dir, pattern) {
    let files = fs.readdirSync(dir).map(file => path.join(dir, file));
    for(let file of files) {
        const stat = fs.statSync(file);
        if (stat.isDirectory()) {
            deleteRecursively(file, pattern);
        } else {
            if (pattern.test(file)) {
                console.log(`Deleting file: ${file}...`);
                // Uncomment the next line once you're happy with the files being logged!
                try { 
                    //fs.unlinkSync(file);
                } catch (err) {
                    console.error(`An error occurred deleting file ${file}: ${err.message}`);
                } 
            }
        }
    }
}

deleteRecursively('./some_dir', /\.json$/);
```

I've actually left the line that deletes the file commented out.. I'd suggest you run the script and be happy the files that are logged are the right ones. Then just uncomment the fs.unlinkSync line to delete the files.

Comment: Thank you! It deletes all json files perfectly. But the problem is in my program for every run, there is a json file automatically created inside of my direction. Your code deletes files but always one file is left.

Comment: Oh great, well thank you very much for testing it.. is the file always left in the same directory?

Comment: Do you see the file appearing in the log statement, "Deleting file: <file>..", if not perhaps the file has not been created yet? It may also be that there is a permission issue with deleting the file. You could wrap the unlinkSync call with a try/catch to log any error arising from this. Hope this helps!

Comment: Glad to hear that! Good luck with the project!